# How to deploy Google App Script to API Server on GCP?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I'm working with Google App Script (GAS code) to get json data from client and export to pdf file. It works very well and now I want to deploy my GAS code to GCP to receive json data and return pdf file.

I hope that I can build a simple HTTP server to receive json and do some logic by Google App Script and return the result to the client.

I already connected between GAS code to standard GCP project by following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects)

This is my Google App Script code:

```
function fetchData() {
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(inputJson);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var dataLen = jsonData.data.length;
  sheet.getRange(7, 1, dataLen, 3).clear();
  sheet.getRange(7, 1, dataLen, 3).setValues(jsonData.data);
}
```

This is my json input:

```
"data": [
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"],
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"],
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"],
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
]
```

How can I build a server that connect with Google App Script to receive that json (from Postman...) ?

Any advice is welcome!!!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, is the use of Web Apps suitable for your goal? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike oh yeah, that's what I want to know, thank you very much. Can you post your answer to make sure I can upvote for you ;)

Comment: @Tanaike and one thing I want to ask, I saw documentation that Google App Scripts just support doGet (GET) or doPost (POST) function, what's about UPDATE and DELETE api ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also I thought that this information might be useful for other users. So I posted an answer by adding the information and the answer for your reply comment. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to create a HTTP server.
- You want to give a JSON data and retrieve the output result from the server.
- You want to use Google Apps Script.

In order to achieve above situation, I would like to propose to use Web Apps. The flow for achieving is as follows.

1. Create the script using Google Apps Script.
2. Deploy the script as Web Apps.

   - In this situation, you can use GET and/or POST method for Web Apps. If the JSON data is large, I recommend to use POST method.
3. Request the endpoint of Web Apps including the JSON data.

   - By this, Web Apps gets the JSON data and processes it, then returns the result.

By above flow, you can retrieve the processed result at the client side.

#### Note:

- When you use Web Apps, if you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.
- Unfortunately, in the current stage, Web Apps can use GET and POST methods, and PATCH, PUT and DELETE methods cannot be used.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer but is there any other solutions? I found that deploy as web apps have many disadvantages like authentication or authorization...
For example, `Deploy API as executable...`

Comment: @Tran B. V. Son Thank you for replying. For Web Apps, unfortunately, I couldn't understand about ``I found that deploy as web apps have many disadvantages like authentication or authorization``. So can you post it by including more information as new question? By this, users including me can think of your situation. I would like to confirm about it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Yes sure, please check my new question, thanks for your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319332/authentication-when-deploy-google-app-script-as-a-web-app

Comment: @Tran B. V. Son Thank you for your response. I saw it just now. I noticed that an answer has already been posted as a comment. I think that it will lead to the solution of your issue.