# Authentication when deploy Google App Script as a Web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I deployed my Google App Script code as a Web server and it worked very well. But I noticed that my web server couldn't be public for other people except people in my organization.

[image]

How I can public my web server to everyone without changing my organization email?
Any advice is welcome!!!

Comment: You [should have an anonymous user option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) -- if this is missing, I would check with your G Suite administrator to see if you might be missing permissions which would allow you to publish a web app to be accessed outside your domain.

Comment: But what if I want to deploy for my organization, and how I know the request come to Google App Script is from my organization email?

Comment: You mean you want to have some features accessible to users within your domain, and others available for anyone? You could use separate scripts, or maybe check the [user's group](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group) or  [email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user); I'm not familiar with any better ways to check that or any potential security issues that may have.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. For now, I want to publish my GAS to my organization, and it works very well when I use the browser (with my organization email). But if I use Postman to call deployed GAS URL, I have to login with an organization account, so how I call that URL from postman or terminal ?

Comment: You can login to the URL and authorize the app before accessing it, or have the app open the browser window for the user.