# How to authenticate deployed Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building Google App Script product, when I deployed GAS project, I only want people in my organization can access to the app. It's ok with the browser when user already login with my organization email. But how I can access deployed URL by Postman or Terminal, Do I need access token or anything else?
Any advice is welcome!

[image]

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication when deploy Google App Script as a Web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319332/authentication-when-deploy-google-app-script-as-a-web-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest to use the [OAuth PlayGround](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) using the [Google Apps Script deployed projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments). You can also check this similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076503/using-postman-to-access-oauth-2-0-google-apis) for more solutions regarding your issue.